# How To Edit The Minecraft servers.dat File

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I was looking through my .minecraft folder on Windows 10, and I decided I wanted to edit the servers.dat file. The reasons behind this are very complex, so I wont explain anything other than the fact that I need to open that file. I tried using NBT editor and researched the internet, but there doesn't seem to be any way to open that file. NBT editor only gives me an error saying this:

```
Error while opening File "C:\Users\<my_user_name>\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\servers.dat":
Not in GZIP format
```

I am assuming this means that the data structure is wrong, and there is no way to access it with NBT editor. Does anyone know what the best way to open this file would be?

Answer (score 1):

[NBTExplorer](https://github.com/jaquadro/NBTExplorer) opens my servers.dat file just fine.